# I got error with these code and don't know the reason

Tags: php

This is the piece of code, i think i am confused because everything is all in place but it is not working.

Dreamweaver says:It say there is a syntax error in line 50, which is the last line in beneath code`?>`

```
<?php
array_walk(array('big', 'small', 'original'), function(&$v, $k) {   
        $dir = ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/' . $v;
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        }
    }

?>
```

As i am newbie to PHP so it is difficult for me to find it out. If there is any software to detect these kind of problems then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tip: always turn on error reporting, maybe a permission issue

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Dreamweaver says:It say there is a syntax error in line 50

Comment: missing ) after the last }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing bracket and colon of the `array_walk` function:

```
$array = array('big', 'small', 'original');
array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k) {
        $dir = ROOT_PATH.'user/upload/'.$row['UserName'].'/avatar/' . $v;
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        }
    }
);
```

If your IDE or text editor doesn't provide you with hints about unclosed brackets and so on, you can turn on error reporting on a per-script basis by adding the following to the top of your php scripts:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in E:\Easyphp\www\index.php on line 1

Comment: What's line 1? You have to add the error-reporting lines after the initial `<?php` declaration.

Comment: i know, in browser it says line 49 which is line 1 in here

Comment: declare the array in a separate variable and then do the array walk.